# settimeofday() on Android results in errno - Read-only file system

Tags: c, linux, time, android-ndk

I am trying to set the device time in NDK native code in C. As far as I have seen the best solution is to use settimeofday().

```
struct timeval tv = {timet, 0};
struct timezone tz = {timezone, daylight}; // The second timezone is long int. Time lib extern which perfectly suits here.
if (settimeofday(&tv, &tz) != 0)
{
    LOG(("settimeofday() failed: %s", strerror(errno)));
}
```

Results in

```
settimeofday() failed: Read-only file system
```

Are there any other way in native to set time? Is it possible at all? I looked at the Read-only file system part of the problems, but I do NOT have Rooted device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the device time without sufficient permission, and an app won't be able to get that permission on an un-rooted device.  From the man page:

```
   EPERM  The calling process has insufficient privilege to call  settime-
          ofday(); under Linux the CAP_SYS_TIME capability is required.
```

Even if you did manage to set it, it would likely be overwritten the next time the device got a time update over the network.

It's a little weird that you're getting EROFS instead of EPERM.

Comment: So setting time is only possible in Application context using Java APIs :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Android System clock is mapped to "/dev/alarm" which has only read permission for non system apps. So, if you are trying to change the time on a stock device you are out of luck. You have to use either -

1. Settings App (which is a system app runs with system privileged) or
2. Sign your app with system privileged (which is impossible unless you are working for vendor or rolling out your own FW)

So, if you want to change the system time using only your app then you have to change the permission of "/dev/alarm" to be writable (chmod 666 /dev/alarm from adb shell). To do that you need a rooted device.

Once you have changed the permission you will be able to change the time using Java API from you app (SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis()).

I am still unable to make it work with settimeofday() or clock_settime().

Hope this helps.